# using libstreaming to get the thumbnail of stream being published

Tags: rtsp, live-streaming

Hy everyone
i am using libstreaming in my project and it works great for publishing stream from android device to Wowza server, now the issue is that i need to get thumbnail of the stream being published to the server.
For this purpose, i guess i need to grab the first frame of the stream being published, but how do i do that???
the examples mentioned [here](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) doesn't show anything related to this.
any help in this regard will be highly appreciated
thanks in advance.....

Comment: @khurranmengr, did you find a solution on how to get a video thumbnail? I stuck with this problem.

Comment: @jayellos unfortunately, i couldn't find any trick at application end. Now i am doing it at server end...

Comment: @khurramengr I am unable to stream the video to wowza server in some particular mobiles like Micromax,lenovo etc . can u please tell me the solution as u said u are able to stream the video to server. can you please give me ur mail id . hitsandroid021@gmail.com is my mailId.

Answer (score 1):

@khurramengr,
There are two ways
1) You can write a custom module in wowza to record the live stream and then use FFMPEG command to take snapshot of the file.
Refer: http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?577-Custom-module-to-create-single-frame-snapshots-of-live-and-VOD-stream

2) Enable recording option in Wowza media engine-> live. So automatically every stream recorded under content folder. You can use FFMPEG to generate thumbnail for available recorded mp4 in content folder.

I tried and both working, let me know in-case of doubts.

~Manikandan Chandran

Answer (score -1):

It is very late, but I hope to help other people who come later.
I think the solution is using Wowza Transcoder: https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?307-How-to-get-thumbnail-images-from-Wowza-Transcoder-with-an-HTTP-Provider
Have a look at function onGrabFrame(TranscoderNativeVideoFrame videoFrame), the image is given:

```
public void onGrabFrame(TranscoderNativeVideoFrame videoFrame)
    {           
        BufferedImage image = TranscoderStreamUtils.nativeImageToBufferedImage(videoFrame);
        if (image != null)
        {

            getLogger().info("ModuleTestTranscoderFrameGrab#GrabResult.onGrabFrame: "+image.getWidth()+"x"+image.getHeight());

            String storageDir = appInstance.getStreamStoragePath();

            File pngFile = new File(storageDir+"/thumbnail.png");
            File jpgFile = new File(storageDir+"/thumbnail.jpg");

            try
            {
                if (pngFile.exists())
                    pngFile.delete();
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", pngFile);
                getLogger().info("ModuleTestTranscoderFrameGrab#GrabResult.onGrabFrame: Save image: "+pngFile);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                getLogger().error("ModuleTestTranscoderFrameGrab.grabFrame: File write error: "+pngFile);
            }

            try
            {
                if (jpgFile.exists())
                    jpgFile.delete();
                ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", jpgFile);
                getLogger().info("ModuleTestTranscoderFrameGrab#GrabResult.onGrabFrame: Save image: "+jpgFile);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                getLogger().error("ModuleTestTranscoderFrameGrab.grabFrame: File write error: "+jpgFile);
            }
        }
    }
```

Regards,